# Minimum of ordered categorical data in Panda DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

I have a Pandas DataFrame with one Serie containing ordered Categorical data. Some value of this Serie may be missing (NaN). I want to get the minimum without taking into account NaNs but I obtained strange results ...

**Code:**

```
raw_cat = pd.Categorical(["a", "b", "c", "a"],
                         categories=["b", "c", "d"],
                         ordered=True)
s = pd.Series(raw_cat)
raw_cat.min(numeric_only=True), s.min(numeric_only=True)
```

**Output:**

```
('b', nan)
```

**Expected output:**

```
('b', 'b')
```

What am I misunderstanding? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm using pandas 0.24.1. And you ?

Comment: I am getting the desired output when running your code

Comment: Cannot reproduce error.

Comment: Under `0.24.0` same bug

Comment: @PythonNewb which Pandas version do you have?

Comment: It works for me with the version `0.23.4` and below.

Comment: I have 0.23.4, my bad for not checking. Seems to be unintended behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was a regression of Pandas 0.24.0 and above. It will be correct in Pandas 0.24.2.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25299